# How do I connect to MySQL using 32/64-bit ODBC drivers from within SSIS?

Tags: mysql, ssis, odbc, driver

I have written an SSIS package and I'm having trouble with connecting to the MySQL server.
Ive tried both .NET connector and ODBC and I've hit issues with both.

The .NET connector has a known issue with dynamic queries and gives an error regarding not finding column *`P1`* (which is a variable).

The recommended route to get past this is to use ODBC to connect. When i use the ODBC connector i get an error regarding memory issues with connecting to MySQL.

I have installed both 64 and 32 bit ODBC MySQL drivers and setup my ODBC connection, but it doesn't fix my issue.

I have tried just entering a connection string, but this leads me back to the memory error.
When reading some online guides it mentions two different Data Sources needing to be setup, one for 32-bit and one for 64 bit, but in Windows 7 I cannot see a 64 bit Data Sources program?

I have also found people mention using a specific *`mysql.data.dll`* file but i cannot find this file nor where to put it or reference it.

Answer (score 0):

Read the below Microsoft KB to find the executables location to configure the `32-bit` and `64-bit` ODBC data sources. You need to configure the appropriate ODBC source so you can view it in BIDS or make the SSIS package run within an SQL Server Agent job.

[*Microsoft KB 942976*](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942976)

- **`32-bit`** version of **`Odbcad32.exe`** file is in *`%systemdrive%\Windows\SysWoW64`* folder.
- **`64-bit`** version of **`Odbcad32.exe`** file is in *`%systemdrive%\Windows\System32`* folder.

System drive would be the drive where you have installed the operating system.